# Is *p++ += 2 well defined?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, post-increment, compound-assignment

I'm not sure whether statement below is well defined by standard C or not

```
*p1++ += 2;
```

or other similar statement:

```
*E1++ <operator>= E2
```

From standard C about post-increment:

> The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
>   After the result is obtained, the value of the operand is incremented.
>   (That is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it.) See the
>   discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
>   information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of
>   operations on pointers. The side effect of updating the stored value
>   of the operand shall occur between the previous and the next sequence
>   point.

And about coumpund-assignment:

> A compound assignment of the form E1 op= E2 differs from the simple
>   assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2) only in that the lvalue E1 is
>   evaluated only once.

Comment: Well, what exactly triggered your suspicion that it might be undefined? To me, for one example, everything looks fine, which makes it difficult to me to even start answering the question: I don't know what to focus on.

Comment: Dont write codes in project like this, except you research on it.

Comment: Writing this kind of illegible code just to stuff more code on one line is bad programming. :)

Comment: Who cares. If this code is any real program it would be immediately removed. In reality it should never pass a code review and get into the code base. So whether it does what the original developer expects is irrelevant as the next developer to see will **not** immediately understand it and thus refactor it out of the code base.

Comment: The question is relevant, if there was a wider context e.g. "my program behaves differently when compiled with GCC and Visual C++. I came across this line in it - could this be the problem?"

Answer (score 23):

Let's rewrite slightly to make it more clear:

```
(*p1++) += 2
```

So the old value of `p1` will be dereferenced, and 2 will be added to its referent.  And `p1` will be incremented after it is dereferenced (or at least, after its old value is loaded and waiting to be dereferenced).  There's no problem here: none of the pieces is used more than once.

That being said, you should consider rewriting the code for clarity:

```
*p1 += 2;
++p1;
```

Comment: "then" isn't quite right, the side effect of += could happen before or after the side effect of ++. They key is that they are on different scalar objects.

Answer (score 3):

Postfix increment operator (`++`)  gives the value of operand, i.e. it gives an **r-value**. The r-value implies that it be used on the left of the assignment operator (`=`) as an operand.

```
int i = 0;
i++ = 0   // [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

In case of

```
*p1++ += 2;
```

postfix `++` is not applied on `*p1`, but it is applied to pointer `p1++`. This is because postfix `++` has higher precedence than that of derereference operator `*`. So, compiler will parse the above statement as

```
*(p1++) += 2;
```

and this says that:

- `*p1` must be evaluated (to produce a variable) before adding `2` and assigning the result to it.
- Result to be stored to `*p1` must be evaluated before the increment to `p1`.
- Once `*p1` is evaluated, `p1` can be increment at any time.

Comment: Is the last statement guaranteed in C++ ?

Comment: I would have thought that once `p1` is evaluated, `p1` can be increment at any time.